# Powershell can not find sysctl

Tags: powershell, sysctl

Running `sysctl` in powershell gives the following error:

```
sysctl : The term 'sysctl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sysctl
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sysctl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It used to work fine a time ago, but stopped working after I manually removed some python related folders. Probably I've removed something else, but now I'd like to make it work without reinstalling my Windows.

What I've tried:

- reinstall Ubuntu from Windows Market

What's interesting, in I run `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` from WLS - it gives me `permission denied on key "vm.max_map_count"`

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: sysctl is not a native Powershell command, reinstalling Windows isn't going to do you any good. It's probably part of module you've removed

Comment: Can you run anything from your Ubuntu install in PowerShell?

Comment: @RobbieCrash I'm new to that, give an example, please. I can run `ps` if that's it

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: In the scope of integration tests, I'm running Elastic Search in the docker container. It failed to start because it requires more memory. I mentioned `sysctl` used to work before, so previously I fixed the same error with the command: sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`